# No Chart on Shapelets-platform dataapps with Altair charts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, altair

I was trying to create a simple data app for an interactive work presentation. So my code is running smoothly, however, when I go on the data app the whole page is blank and I don't know what is happening. Would it be possible to help me?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from shapelets.apps import DataApp

df = pd.read_csv('data_income.csv')

# Create a data app
app = DataApp(""Presentation"")


# add the points from papa_person to the map
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='postalCode:N',
    y='Income:Q',
    color='Feature:N',
    tooltip=['postalCode:N', 'Feature:N', 'Count:Q']
).properties(width=600, height=400, title=f'Income by Zipcode').interactive()

app.altair_chart(chart=chart)

app.register()
```

[empty dataapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMrfi.png)

Comment: If you chart code works fine outside the app, this could be an issue with shapelet's altair integration and you might get better responses asking on their GitHub issue tracker or tagging this question with their helptag (if there is one)

Answer (score 0):

don't worry there is just a small problem with your code that you can fix in only one line. In your case, you forgot to place the chart on the app which ultimately doesn't place anything on the dataapp. You can fix it by
`app.place(app.altair_chart(chart=chart))`
and now it should work like a charm.
Here is the link to the documentation for more information https://new.shapelets.io/doc/user-guide/dataapps/widgets.html#action-components